# org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSFileException: Error reading data: unexpected compression code for string variable

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet which reads and writes the data. here is as snippet of my code

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    SPSSFile file = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(getServerDiretory() + "dabadeba_2011.01.03.sav");

        if (!f.exists()) {
            System.out.println("not found");
            return;
        }
        file = new SPSSFile(f);

        file.loadMetadata();
        file.loadData();

        if (file == null) {
            System.err.println("vai");
            return;
        }

        Document doc = file.getDDI2();

        //set up a transformer
        TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.CDATA_SECTION_ELEMENTS, "yes");

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        trans.transform(source, result);
        String xmlString = sw.toString();

        writeToFile(xmlString);

        out.println(xmlString);

    } catch (TransformerException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SPSSReaderServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SPSSReaderServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SPSSFileException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SPSSReaderServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        out.close();
        if (file != null) {
            file.close();
            System.out.println("done, file closed");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working, until I to refresh the JSP and call this servlet again. Here is the error I get after refreshing the page:

```
SEVERE: org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSFileException: Error reading data: unexpected compression code for string variable
    at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSDataRecord.read(SPSSDataRecord.java:161)
    at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSDataRecord.read(SPSSDataRecord.java:54)
    at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSFile.loadData(SPSSFile.java:1277)
    at ge.geostat.metadata.web.servlet.SPSSReaderServlet.processRequest(SPSSReaderServl‌​et.java:63)
    at ge.geostat.metadata.web.servlet.SPSSReaderServlet.doGet(SPSSReaderServlet.java:1‌​40)
```

When I redeploy the application and run it, it works fine. I guess it is a memory issue, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please check the catalina log file (if you use tomcat) and let us know where the exception occurs.

Comment: I use Glasfish, here is the hole exception:

SEVERE: org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSFileException: Error reading data: unexpected compression code for string variable
 at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSDataRecord.read(SPSSDataRecord.java:161)
 at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSDataRecord.read(SPSSDataRecord.java:54)
 at org.opendatafoundation.data.spss.SPSSFile.loadData(SPSSFile.java:1277)
 at ge.geostat.metadata.web.servlet.SPSSReaderServlet.processRequest(SPSSReaderServlet.java:63)
 at ge.geostat.metadata.web.servlet.SPSSReaderServlet.doGet(SPSSReaderServlet.java:140)

Comment: Do you close the file after writing the data into it?

Comment: Sure, here it is:

`private void writeToFile(String template) {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {

            File newTextFile = new File(getServerDiretory() + "test.xml");
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
            fileWriter.write(template);
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Is this occurs after each refreshing? or it does not occurs anymore?

Comment: Program works only on the first run (after deployment), after that it doesn't matter how many times I refresh the page - error is the same

Comment: I am sure that this problem occurs because you don't close the file. Please make sure using logging before and after closing the file!

Comment: I've commented the "file write" part. Still without any luck. Thanks for your help

`//writeToFile(xmlString);`

Comment: OK, So please mark the bellow solution as accepted solution to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your help. I've figured out the problem, it might help someone using the org.opendatafoundation SPSS reader class

So, the problem was with the method loadData(), it uses the static variable, which has to be reset on the second call: SPSSDataRecord.clusterIndex = 8;

```
    /**
 * Load the data section of the file into the variables in memory. This may be expensive on memory, use with care on large datasets
 *
 * @throws SPSSFileException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void loadData() throws IOException, SPSSFileException {
    if (dataStartPosition < 1) {
        // this has not been initialized, we don't actually know where the data starts
        throw new SPSSFileException("Error: data location pointer not initialized.");

    }
    SPSSDataRecord data = new SPSSDataRecord();

    SPSSDataRecord.clusterIndex = 8; //---This is the fix!!!
    seek(dataStartPosition);
    for (int i = 0; i < infoRecord.numberOfCases; i++) {
        // log("\nRECORD "+(i+1)+" offset "+this.getFilePointer());
        data.read(this);
    }
    isDataLoaded = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you will get an exception when you refreshing the page, it will occurs because you forgot to close the file. I am sure that the problem is that. Because the first time that you build your project it works and after that it doesn't work. You should call the `close` method of file in `finally` block.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? This sounds more like a comment.

Comment: We had some collaborates in above comments. So I explained a little! The post has been edited!

Comment: From the comments on the question, what part of *"Still without any luck"* didn't you understand? The code posted in the comment also just shows the close call in `finally`. Did you miss that?

Comment: Thanks! I added the comment above because the review system picked your answer as "low quality" for being too short. In cases like that, us reviewers are asked if the post looks good, or should be deleted? So, your answer was at risk. +1 for adding further explanation!